# How to fill a gtk grid with buttons?

Tags: c, button, gtk

I remember there was a formula in **C** to fill automatically a grid with buttons, and I can't find the page where I found it, can someone help me with that? I remember there were two FOR in use. Its is in GTK+ 3.0 and on C.

Comment: What is your code? Did you add the button into hbox or vbox?

Comment: Of course there should be two `for` loops, one for each column and one for rows.

Comment: I got the grid from a glade file with gtk_builder_get_object. The grid is on a hbox.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// insert 9 buttons to a grid, 3x3.
void fill_grid_with_buttons(GtkWidget *grid) 
{
  GtkWidget *button;
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
      button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("label");
      gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, i, j, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the same as you, I got no errors but program wont start.

GtkWidget *grid1, *grid2;
GtkWidget *button[145];
int i,j, k = 0;

grid1 = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "grid1" ) );
    for( i = 0; i < 13; i++ ){
     for( j = 0; i < 13; j++ ){
      button[k] = gtk_button_new ();
      gtk_grid_attach( grid1, button[k], i, j, 1, 1 );
      k++;
     }

    }

Comment: Sorry, dont know how to format text to appear as a code block :(

Comment: Ok, I've upload the whole demo code to github. It can be found  here: https://github.com/LiuLang/gtk-test/tree/master/grid-fill-with-buttons